# Передать функцию в аргумент декоратора disnake.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Программирую своего бота на disnake. Это аналог discord.py но более продвинутый в плане функций, особых отличий вы не найдёте.

Много воды лить не буду. В Disnake существует декоратор `@commands.dynamic_cooldown(cooldown, type=BucketType.default)` Декоратор схож с декоратором `@commands.cooldown()`, просто в первом случае декоратор может принимать за место аргумента `cooldown` функцию принимающую параметр типа disnake.Message и возвращающую время перезарядки.

Вопрос, как правильно передать в аргумент декоратора функцию с параметром типа disnake.Message?

Код:

```
@bot.slash_command(description='Очищает данное количесво сообщений.')                                                                             
@commands.dynamic_cooldown(await give_guild_cooldown(), commands.BucketType.user)                                                                 
async def clear(ctx, reason: int = commands.Param(name="number_of_messages_to_clear")):    # slash-command clear                                  
    await chq_moder_role(ctx=ctx)                                                                                                                 
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=int(reason))                                                                                                    
    await ctx.response.send_message(embed=disnake.Embed(description=f'**{reason} сообщений(e) удалено!** :white_check_mark:'), delete_after=60)
```

Примечание: сама функция give_guild_cooldown() ещё не прописана.

Примечание 2: ошибок нету, я просто не знаю откуда в этом декораторе можно получить объект disnake.Message

Огромное спасибо за ответ!

Comment: А какая сейчас ошибка или что не работает?

Comment: @Ivan, ошибки нету, я просто не имею представления откуда можно взять disnake.Message в декораторе и как его правильно передать